# Why does this JLabel have 2 positions?

Tags: java, swing, java-threads

I'm making this program where a JLabel controlled by the user will move on a 500x500 frame, but for some reason it seems to have two positions and when it moves it just flickers between them. What is causing this?

[This is how it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9rnd.gif)

Here's the main window:

```
package guipkg1;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import guipkg1.PlayerMove;

public class KeyListenerPage extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    public static JLabel player = new JLabel();
    public static boolean isGoingLeft = false;
    public static boolean isGoingUp = false;
    public static boolean isGoingRight = false;
    public static boolean isGoingDown = false;
    PlayerMove pmove = new PlayerMove();
    KeyListenerPage(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        
        player.setBounds(0,0,50,50);
        player.setText(":)");
        this.add(player);
        
        
        
        pmove.start();
    } 
        
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode()==37 || e.getKeyCode()==65) {
            isGoingLeft = true;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] going left");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==38 || e.getKeyCode()==87) {
            isGoingUp = true;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] going up");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==39 || e.getKeyCode()==68) {
            isGoingRight = true;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] going right");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==40 || e.getKeyCode()==83) {
            isGoingDown = true;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] going down");
        }
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode()==37 || e.getKeyCode()==65) {
            isGoingLeft = false;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] stopped going left");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==38 || e.getKeyCode()==87) {
            isGoingUp = false;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] stopped going up");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==39 || e.getKeyCode()==68) {
            isGoingRight = false;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] stopped going right");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode()==40 || e.getKeyCode()==83) {
            isGoingDown = false;
            System.out.println("[KeyListenerPage] stopped going down");
        }
    }
}
```

And the thread moving the player:

```
package guipkg1;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class PlayerMove extends Thread implements Runnable {
    boolean movingLeft = KeyListenerPage.isGoingLeft;
    boolean movingUp = KeyListenerPage.isGoingUp;
    boolean movingRight = KeyListenerPage.isGoingRight;
    boolean movingDown = KeyListenerPage.isGoingDown;
    JLabel player = KeyListenerPage.player;
    boolean canMoveLeft = false;
    boolean canMoveRight = true;
    boolean canMoveUp = false;
    boolean canMoveDown = true;
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running");
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            movingLeft = KeyListenerPage.isGoingLeft;
            movingUp = KeyListenerPage.isGoingUp;
            movingRight = KeyListenerPage.isGoingRight;
            movingDown = KeyListenerPage.isGoingDown;
            if(movingLeft && canMoveLeft) {
                player.setBounds(player.getWidth(), player.getHeight(), player.getX()-10, player.getY());
                player.setVisible(true);
                if(player.getX()<=0) {
                    canMoveLeft = false;
                }
                if(player.getX()<490) {
                    canMoveRight = true;
                }
            } 
            if(movingRight && canMoveRight) {
                player.setBounds(player.getWidth(), player.getHeight(), player.getX()+10, player.getY());
                player.setVisible(true);
                if(player.getX()>0) {
                    canMoveLeft = true;
                }
                if(player.getX()>=490) {
                    canMoveRight = false;
                }
            }
            if(movingUp && canMoveUp) {
                player.setBounds(player.getWidth(), player.getHeight(), player.getX(), player.getY()-10);
                player.setVisible(true);
                if(player.getY()<=0) {
                    canMoveUp = false;
                }
                if(player.getY()<490) {
                    canMoveDown = true;
                }
            } 
            if(movingDown && canMoveDown) {
                player.setBounds(player.getWidth(), player.getHeight(), player.getX(), player.getY()+10);
                player.setVisible(true);
                if(player.getY()>0) {
                    canMoveUp = true;
                }
                if(player.getY()>=490) {
                    canMoveDown = false;
                }
            } 
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by looking at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Swing is NOT thread safe and is single threaded.  This means you should not try to modify the UI from out side the EDT or run long running tasks from within it.  See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)  for the most common solution to the aforementioned problem.  Finally, see [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to fix all the issues with `KeyListener`

Comment: Using Swing components (ie `JLabel`) is not recommended, you'd better off following a custom paint route.  See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why does it flicker?*

Because your arguments to `player.setBounds()` are in the wrong order.

According to the [JLabel#setBounds() JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,int,int,int)) the arguments are in the order `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`.

But your code calls the method with the arguments

```
player.setBounds(player.getWidth(), player.getHeight(), player.getX(), player.getY()+10);
```

where it should be

```
player.setBounds(player.getX(), player.getY()+10, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
```

Also note that **Swing is not thread-safe**. If you want to change anything on a displayed Swing component you must do it on the Swing EDT, for example by rewriting `PlayerMove.run()` as

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("running");
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::move);
    }
}
```

And moving the remaining code from `PlayerMove.run()` into a new `move()` method:

```
private void move() {
    movingLeft = KeyListenerPage.isGoingLeft;
    movingUp = KeyListenerPage.isGoingUp;
    movingRight = KeyListenerPage.isGoingRight;
    movingDown = KeyListenerPage.isGoingDown;
    if(movingLeft && canMoveLeft) {
        player.setBounds(player.getX()-10, player.getY(), player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        player.setVisible(true);
        if(player.getX()<=0) {
            canMoveLeft = false;
        }
        if(player.getX()<490) {
            canMoveRight = true;
        }
    }
    if(movingRight && canMoveRight) {
        player.setBounds(player.getX()+10, player.getY(), player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        player.setVisible(true);
        if(player.getX()>0) {
            canMoveLeft = true;
        }
        if(player.getX()>=490) {
            canMoveRight = false;
        }
    }
    if(movingUp && canMoveUp) {
        player.setBounds(player.getX(), player.getY()-10, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        player.setVisible(true);
        if(player.getY()<=0) {
            canMoveUp = false;
        }
        if(player.getY()<490) {
            canMoveDown = true;
        }
    }
    if(movingDown && canMoveDown) {
        player.setBounds(player.getX(), player.getY()+10, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        player.setVisible(true);
        if(player.getY()>0) {
            canMoveUp = true;
        }
        if(player.getY()>=490) {
            canMoveDown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this solution still works with a separate thread (i.e. `PlayerMove` still extends `Thread` and you still have to call `pmove.start();` in the `KeyListenerPage`)

---

As MadProgrammer has already commented the better way would be to [use a Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Such a solution would change your code somewhat.

The `PlayerMove` class would change into

```
public class PlayerMove implements ActionListener {
    boolean movingLeft = false;
    boolean movingUp = false;
    boolean movingRight = false;
    boolean movingDown = false;
    JLabel player = KeyListenerPage.player;
    boolean canMoveLeft = false;
    boolean canMoveRight = true;
    boolean canMoveUp = false;
    boolean canMoveDown = true;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // here is all the moving code, 
        // i.e. what in your solution was in the run() method
        // but without the looping
        // The Timer will call this every 20ms for you
    }
}
```

And in the `KeyListenerPage()` constructor you would replace

```
    pmove.start();
```

with

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, pmove);
    timer.start();
```

There is no longer a "never ending loop" needed in your code - the `Timer` now takes care that the `pmove.actionPerformed()` is called every 20ms.

This block of code:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("running");
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::move);
    }
}
```

can be removed entirely by replacing the `move()` method with the `actionPerformed()` method (the code in the method doesn't need to change!) and by replacing `pmove.start();` with two lines - IMHO a clear improvement.

Comment: The issue with putting everything in the same window is that the window freezes whenever there's a never ending loop or a wait function. That's why I always try to use threads. Is there any alternative?